# Bootstrap 3 and .col-xs-* -- Do you not need rows of 12 units?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I'm a little confused by the Bootstrap 3 documentation and thus usage of the `.col-xs-*` classes.

The docs for [Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) say that all of the grid systems use 12 columns.

If you take a look at Bootstrap 3's docs for an [Example Mobile and Desktop](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed) layout they show the first row's `.col-xs-*` classes totaling 18 column units.

What gives?  How can this be?  Are the docs wrong?

Thank you

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014782/bootstrap3-is-it-valid-for-1-row-to-have-infinity-columns

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bootstrap is a 12 column rid, but you can put more than 12 columns in a row. The remaining columns will simply wrap onto the next line below, depending on the viewport.

In this example, on "md" viewports (≥992px), the contents would span 12 columns total (8 + 4). But on "xs" (<768px) the content would span 18 columns, there would be one full row (12 columns) and then below it a half-row (6 columns).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

md...

```
|    8   |  4 |
```

xs...

```
|     12     |
|   6  |
```

EDIT: Make sure to check out the [Responsive Column Reset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) section of the documentation if you run into any issues with columns not wrapping correctly.

Comment: If you have 3 columns of col-md-6 (for example) where the first is higher than the other 2, you will not get proper alignment on the left for the 2nd row. The 2nd column will be placed next to the first, but the 3rd column will not go under the first column since it is floated and the first column is a bit heigher. Because of the float left, there is still some place left and the 3rd column will appear under the 2nd column instead of under the 1st as desired.

Comment: @Wouter There is a built-in solution for this. `<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>` See the `Grid System -> Responsive Column Reset` section of the documentation.

Answer (score 10):

Think of the grid layout more in terms of a different grid  for every size, `lg`, `md`, `sm`, and `xs` (or break points to be specific) that use the same markup. It might help to break open a few browser instances and an example of a grid layout. Follow along with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mffox/qdXLr/2/), or this markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-1">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 col-lg-1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-1">.col-xs-12 .col-md-6 col-lg-1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-1">.col-xs-12 .col-md-6 col-lg-1</div>
</div>
```

You'll need to know your viewport's width in pixels, so consider a [browser plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/viewport) that makes this information readily available or open up a console and run this snippet:

> Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)

---

**Start with a viewport > 1200 pixels:**

[image: col-lg]

The actual columns are decided by the `col-lg-*` classes because of the breakpoint. This will create a grid for that breakpoint.

Now look at the other two break points, `col-sm-*` and `col-xs-*`.

**`col-sm-*` in affect:**

[image: col-sm]

**`col-xs-*` in affect:**

[image: col-xs]

The break points allow you to create a completely new grid per size. So, in theory, the rows  act as a "strict" new row, where as the `col` numbers like

```
<div class='col-xs-12'>col-xs-12</div>
<div class='col-xs-12'>col-xs-12</div>
```

***can*** force a new row if the sum > 12. This is so that you don't have to have umpteen different markup templates for different breakpoints. They are guides.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of rows a column occupies is the last number of the class.

So for example, these following classes:

```
.col-xs-12 .col-md-8  
.col-xs-6 .col-md-4
```

will result in a single row on the md-width displays but one and a half row on xs-width displays.
This simply means that on small displays those elements won't display side-by-side, but instead on top of each other.

Comment: My question is more along the lines of... why do rows of `col-sm`, `col-md`, `col-lg` all add up to 12 column units while `col-xs` seems to not have this constraint... and i can't find it documented in Bootstrap's docs.

Comment: col-xs has the same constraints. I think what you might be confused about is that if you do NOT add col-xs to your class (i.e. col-xs-6), it automatically defaults to col-xs-12 (one whole column width)

Comment: It does *not* default to col-xs-12. It isn't floated. it just has full width as that's the divs default behaviour shining through.

You might think it doesn't matter, but 4 divs of md-6 md-6 lg-6 lg-6 will fail on the medium display, and have the first large div overlay all the floats...