# Bootstrap3 is it valid for 1 row to have infinity columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

Using Bootstrap3 and the grid system. The default settings are 12 columns in the grid system.

Is there any adverse outcomes to writing html similar to:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No it is not possible in bootstrap. But you can write your own media queries to create infinite columns.

Comment: Infinite number columns == infinite number of bytes for your clients to have to download. Be conscious of page size and also the user experience.

Comment: @Dikesh i don't see how media queries has anything to do with this.

Comment: There's nothing invalid about this approach. Check out [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915636/bootstrap-3-and-col-xs-do-you-not-need-rows-of-12-units/21916479#21916479) for a different perspective on _why_

Comment: @t.niese this behavior is supported and documented. For an example see the code block right above [this anchor](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete) in the doc

Comment: @CarrieKendall oh your are right, i always thought it would make problems (but I can't recall why). I  removed my comment as it has a vote, to avoid confusion for further readers.

Comment: It was astounding that people would blindly agree, given I posted proof of the latter :P Thanks @t.niese

Comment: @CarrieKendall That not the only astounding thing around on SO :D. Btw thx for notifying, it is good to know that it can be used that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is absolutely valid and documented markup for bootstrap. Have a look at my answer explaining this idea in depth: [Bootstrap 3 and .col-xs-* -- Do you not need rows of 12 units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915636/bootstrap-3-and-col-xs-do-you-not-need-rows-of-12-units/21916479#21916479) (includes pictures for a visual representation).

From the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed):

```
<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```

If you look at the second example in the code, there are 3 columns, and the `xs` breakpoint has the value `6` for all columns. The sum of those columns being `18` (ie > 12).

This allows you to use the same markup for different row breaks on different breakpoints. The simplified idea is that you don't need to have different markup templates for different viewports. The actual `.row`s are guidelines, not concrete implementations that should only allow for columns equal to or less than 12.

Comment: This was exactly the documentation I was looking for. I saw in practice "it just works®". I also analyzed the CSS which i saw no obvious usages in either columns or rows that would somehow negatively impact proper tiling when there are overflow scenarios.